# React FilePond FileStatus Enum

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am using the [FilePond](https://github.com/pqina/filepond) library to handle my pictures uploads in a React app.

I have a multiupload instance of FilePond, with a maximum of 10 files inside a component which uploads the files to a temporary location and returns the temp ID for each file onUpload.

The problem that I am trying to solve is that I want to disable the submit form button from the component until all images are uploaded.

As I read the [documentation](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-object/#filestatus-enum) there is a `FileStatusEnum` which has some stats about the number of files in que `PROCESSING_QUEUED` and other  relevant information

I want to know how can I access this in order to create a logic based on it

Below is the FilePond Instance

```js
<FilePond
  allowMultiple
  maxFiles={maxFiles}
  acceptedFileTypes={["image/*"]}
  imageTransformOutputMimeType="image/png"
  imageTransformOutputQuality={100}
  server={{
    process: handleProcess,
    revert: handleRevert
  }}
  required={required}
  onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
    setFiles(fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file));
  }}
>
  {files.map(file => (
    <File key={file} src={file} origin="local" />
  ))}
</FilePond>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `onprocessfiles` callback, it's run when all files inside FilePond have been processed.
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#callbacks

Comment: I've added `onprocessfiles={() => console.log('done')}` on the `<FilePond>` after the `onupdatefiles` but nothing seems to happen

Comment: After some playing around I found out that on the production server it works but on development it doesn't, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Are files actually uploaded on dev?

Comment: Yes, the post response is the same as the production, same status code and everything

Comment: Then I honestly don't know. I'd inspect the console and network tab to see if every request is exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I've accepted the response because it solved my issue, I'll investigate further to see what happens on the dev.